# how can i add previous function to this JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here in this JS i have some questions with div class="quiz" okay

and here is the "Next" button is working properly, that is for next Question like 1- 2 - 3 - 4 - and again restart to question - 1

okay Now i want to make "Previous" button that should work to show previous question like Question - 3 to Question - 2 and Question - 4 to Question - 1

i have added previous() function on previous button but it is also showing next question.

my previous() function code is this:

```
function previous() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1, 3],
      scaleY: [1, 1.5],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });

  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == questions.length - 1) {
      question = 0;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question++;
    }

    prepQuestion();
  };
}
```

But this function isn't working to show previous question. What mistake am doing ?

plz make it solve
thanks stackoverflow community.

```js
 var question = 0;

var questions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("quiz")).reduce((carry, item) => {
  carry.push(item.textContent.trim())
  return carry;
}, []);

var anim;
var targets;

function prepQuestion() {
  $("#rect").text(questions[question]);

  var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('#rect');
  textWrappers.forEach(textWrapper => {
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });
  });

  targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#rect .letter'));

  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets,
      scale: [3, 1],
      scaleY: [1.5, 1],
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 400,
      delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
    });
}

// init
prepQuestion();

function next() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1, 3],
      scaleY: [1, 1.5],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });

  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == questions.length - 1) {
      question = 0;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question++;
    }

    prepQuestion();
  };
}

function previous() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1, 3],
      scaleY: [1, 1.5],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });

  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == questions.length - 1) {
      question = 0;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question++;
    }

    prepQuestion();
  };
}
```

```css
        #rect {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: rr;
}

#rect .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#quizss {
display:none;
}

.word {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="quizss">
<div class="quiz">Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-2 : Paper comes from...?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-3 : How many hours in a day?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?</div>
</div>



<div id="rect"></div>



<br>
<Button id="rc" onclick="next()">Next</Button>
<Button id="rc" onclick="previous()">previous</Button>
```

plz make it solve
thanks stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just inverse the next!!

```js
 var question = 0;

var questions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("quiz")).reduce((carry, item) => {
  carry.push(item.textContent.trim())
  return carry;
}, []);

var anim;
var targets;

function prepQuestion() {
  $("#rect").text(questions[question]);

  var textWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('#rect');
  textWrappers.forEach(textWrapper => {
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
      return `<span class="word">` +
        m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
        `</span>`;
    });
  });

  targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#rect .letter'));

  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets,
      scale: [3, 1],
      scaleY: [1.5, 1],
      opacity: [0, 1],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 400,
      delay: (el, i) => 60 * i
    });
}

// init
prepQuestion();

function next() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1, 3],
      scaleY: [1, 1.5],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });

  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == questions.length - 1) {
      question = 0;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question++;
    }

    prepQuestion();
  };
}

function previous() {
  anim = anime.timeline()
    .add({
      targets: targets.reverse(),
      scale: [1, 3],
      scaleY: [1, 1.5],
      opacity: [1, 0],
      translateZ: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 100,
      delay: (el, i) => 30 * i
    });

  anim.complete = () => {
    if (question == 0) {
      question = questions.length - 1;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question--;
    }

    prepQuestion();
  };
}
```

```css
        #rect {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: rr;
}

#rect .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#quizss {
display:none;
}

.word {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="quizss">
<div class="quiz">Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-2 : Paper comes from...?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-3 : How many hours in a day?</div>
<div class="quiz">Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?</div>
</div>



<div id="rect"></div>



<br>
<Button id="rc" onclick="next()">Next</Button>
<Button id="rc" onclick="previous()">previous</Button>
```

Comment: Hello Frenchy,

Can you answer my this question also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127751/how-to-add-second-r2-animation-class-to-this-myslides-div-before-it-show-next-o

Answer (score 1):

In the method 'previous', replace

```js
if (question == 0) {
   // reset question
   question = questions.length - 1;
} 
else {
   question--;
}
```

by

```js
if (question == questions.length - 1) {
      question = 0;
    } // reset question
    else {
      question++;
}
```